# ORTools - Division by territories based on multiple vehicles in multiple days

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis, or-tools, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing

**The problem:**

*Multiple vehicles in multiple days meeting the location's time windows plan - obtaining territories.*

Let's suppose there's a list of locations, each with specified time windows per day in a time frame of 4 to 8 weeks. Each location has a limitation, for example, available visits at Monday and Friday, 09:00 to 17:00. The frequency of visit may vary between 1 and 3 times per week.

The whole plan contains location data - required visits in the next 4/8 weeks. Example:

```
Week: 2, Location: 10001, Visit: 3 times, Days: Tuesday-Saturday-Sunday, Available times: 09:00-17:00.
Week: 3, Location: 10001, Visit: 2 times, Days: Monday-Sunday, Available times: 09:00-13:00.
```

This goes for every location within that 4/8 week mark. The algorithm should solve all locations(or most of them), and generate plan, based on which there will be **territory division**. In other words, I need some sort of clustering per regions based on the algorithm output.

**Desired output:**

The end product should be for example, based on ~20,000 locations the algorithm should create [15 regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OATwd.png). **Each region** should be coverable by **one user** (although locations can be dropped) within the cycle. The user within that territory should be able to cover all the locations(or most of them) daily.

**One approach:**

My first thought was to create a different plan for each day within that 8 weeks, then group the similar solutions together in a cluster, which will output the territory plan.

The downside of this approach might be if in two days, one location is included into a different territory. In that scenario, there might be conflict between deciding which location should be in which territory.

**Another approach**

Maybe VRPTW could do the job, but I'm not sure if that's efficient approach. Given the time windows, I could run a simple VRP with time windows of the whole cycle - representing the repeating locations as new ones with different work hours. At the end, the output could be a bunch of clusters by itself, with a risk that this might be totally mixed up.

**The main idea**

.. is to assign a whole territory to a single user, so that one user will cover only one region in that cycle. In the following 4/8 weeks he should cover all the needs in that region only.

**Next steps**

Next, route optimization can be done within each territory - some advanced TSP for the whole cycle.

**Help**

I understand that this is an advanced concept that is not supported by ORTools, but I have to figure a way to do this. What do you think is a feasible solution to this '*clustering*' problem? Does anyone worked on something similar so far? What are your thoughts on best approach to this type of problem?

*Thanks.*